# create a powershell object in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell

I would like to create a powershell object and pass it values from a textbox but I don't know how to do it. I did it from visual basic but I don't know how to do it in c #

this is my example in vba

```
strPSCommand = ""Get-AdUser "" & txt_userName & "" -Properties * |select-object Name,department,company,extensionAttribute1,title,manager| Export-csv C:\Users\etaarratia\Documents\prueba\nombre.txt""

strDOSCommand = ""powershell -command "" & strPSCommand & """"

Set objShell = CreateObject(""Wscript.Shell"")

Set objExec = objShell.Exec(strDOSCommand)
```

I want to create something similar in c#

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried so far? Have you tried documentation like, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kebab/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c

Comment: Also, look into using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` with `PrincipalContext`, `PrincipalUser`.

Comment: In your example in vb you're not creating a Powershell object: you are creating a shell object and run a Powershell script from it (this is not the same as a real Powershell session which you can create by referencing system.management.automation and assigning a variable to Powershell.Create()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a method in C# that will save the details of the user to the file you are looking for.

**Helper Method to Save User**

This method saves the details you are looking for: `Name,department,company,extensionAttribute1,title,manager`

```
    public static void SaveUser(UserPrincipal user, string textFile)
    {
        DirectoryEntry de = (user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry);
        string thisUser = $"{user.Name},{de.Properties["department"].Value},{de.Properties["extensionAttribute1"].Value},{de.Properties["title"].Value},{de.Properties["manager"].Value.ToString().Replace(",","|")}";
        File.AppendAllLines(textFile, new string[] { thisUser }); // Append a new line with this user.
    }
```

and look up and save the user in main method like this,

**Usage**

Assemblies you will need for this

```
    using System.DirectoryServices;
    using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
    using System;
    using System.IO;
```

and usage will be like this,

```
    string txt_userName = "userId";
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domainName", "userName", "Password");
    // if you are running this script from a system joined to this domain, and logged in with a domain user, simply use
    // PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

    UserPrincipal user = (UserPrincipal)Principal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, txt_userName);
    if (user != null)
    {
        string saveToFile = @"C:\Users\etaarratia\Documents\prueba\nombre.txt";
        SaveUser(user, saveToFile);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Preparation:**

```
using System.Management.Automation; //install with Nuget Package Manager
//Create a new PowerShell Class instance and empty pipeline
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
  // use "AddScript" to add the contents of a script file to the end of the execution pipeline.

  // use "AddCommand" to add individual commands/cmdlets to the end of the execution pipeline.

  PowerShellInstance.AddScript("param($param1) $d = get-date; 
  $s = 'test string value'; " + "$d; $s; $param1; get-service");

  // use "AddParameter" to add a single parameter to the last command/script on the pipeline.
  PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("param1", "parameter 1 value!");
}
```

**Script/Command Execution:**

> Now you have populated the pipeline with scripts, commands and parameters. You can now execute the pipeline either async or synchronously:

**Execute Pipeline synchronously:**

```
// execute pipeline synchronously wihout output
    PowerShellInstance.Invoke();  

 // execute the pipeline symchronously with output
    Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

// loop through each output object item
foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
{
    // if null object was dumped to the pipeline during the script then a null
    // object may be present here. check for null to prevent potential Null Reference Exception.
    if (outputItem != null)
    {
        //do something with the output item 
        // outputItem.BaseOBject
    }
}
```

**Execute Pipeline asynchronously:**

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        // this script has a sleep in it to simulate a long running script
        PowerShellInstance.AddScript("start-sleep -s 10; get-service");

        // begin invoke execution on the pipeline
        IAsyncResult result = PowerShellInstance.BeginInvoke();

        // simulate being busy until execution has completed with sleep or wait
        while (result.IsCompleted == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pipeline is being executed...");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            //optionally add a timeout here...            
        }           
    }
```